# How do I format a static string extracted from an xml file?

Tags: android, textview, android-xml

I am developing an Android app which parses an xml file from a online server and extracts a string from it and stores it in a local variable which is then displayed in a textview. I want some part of the extracted text to be displayed in Bold. How do I achieve that? I can make separate text view for only the Bold part and give it a bold attribute, but then I would have too many views and that would slow down the app.

I have access to the xml file on the server and I can make changes to it if required. Is there any way I could format the text in the xml file itself and then be displayed "as is" in the textview?

Answer (score 2):

Try with

`textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText));`

If `htmlText` is let's say

`example <strong>string</strong>`

this will work.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry if this sounds noobish,
But I have a string from a xml file, the string doesnt have any tags in it.

Comment: Let's say your xml contains the phrase "hello world". You could add the <strong> tag around "world" programmatically before calling Html.fromHtml().

Answer (score 2):

When you set the text in the TextView, you can load basic HTML as well, like so:

> text.setText(Html.fromHtml("Hello <b>world</b>"));

In that example, "world" would be bolded.